# Introduced a new activation function using tensor flow in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to introduce a new activation function in python 2.7 tensorflow. However, I tried by looking at some references, but mostly it is implemented in python3. I implemented it by rewriting it to python 2, but I get the same error every time.

```
class Mylayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
      def __init__(self, output_units, *args, **kwargs):
          self.output_units=output_units
          super(Mylayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      def build(self,input_shape):
           super(Mylayer, self).build(input_shape)
           self.kernel = self.add_variable(“kernel”,shape 
                                 [input_shape[-1].value,self.output_units])
      def call(self,x):
           if x<0:
             newfx=0
           else :
             newfx=x*1.5
           return tf.matmul(newfx,self.kernel)
```

This is my activation function.

```
self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,4], dtype=tf.float32)
self.weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4,4]))
self.bias1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1,4]))
self.weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4,4]))
self.bias2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1, 4]))
self.weights3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4,1]))
self.bias3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
self.layer1 = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(self.inputs, self.weights1) + self.bias1)
self.layer2 = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(self.layer1, self.weights2) + self.bias2)
self.layer3 = Mylayer(tf.matmul(self.layer2, self.weights3) + self.bias3)
self.output_layer = self.layer3
```

This is my network.The last session etc are omitted.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File “capture.py”, line 832, in <module>
   options = readCommand( sys.argv[1:] ) # Get game components based on input
 File “capture.py”, line 683, in readCommand
   redAgents = loadAgents(True, options.red, nokeyboard, redArgs)
 File “capture.py”, line 755, in loadAgents
   return createTeamFunc(indices[0], indices[1], isRed, **args)
 File “/Users/Yuay/research/code1/Pacman-Tournament-Agent/code.py”, line 131, in createTeam
   return [eval(first)(firstIndex, **kwargs), eval(second)(secondIndex, **kwargs)]
 File “/Users/Yuay/research/code1/Pacman-Tournament-Agent/code.py”, line 212, in __init__
   self.loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square((self.nextQ - self.output_layer)))
 File “/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py”, line 869, in binary_op_wrapper
   y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name=“y”)
 File “/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py”, line 1050, in convert_to_tensor
   as_ref=False)
 File “/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py”, line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
   ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
 File “/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py”, line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
 File “/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py”, line 208, in constant
   value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
 File “/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py”, line 442, in make_tensor_proto
   _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
 File “/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py”, line 353, in _AssertCompatible
   (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected float32, got <my.Mylayer object at 0x10385dd50> of type ‘Mylayer’ instead.
```

This is error.

I understand that the returning value is coming  by object rather than float, but I do not know how to fix it.
I do not have enough understanding of tensorflow and deep learning. But in keras this implementation works fine.

Comment: What is the full error traceback?

Comment: Error part has been updated. This is  full error traceback.

Comment: the error doesn't seem to be because you're using a different python version

Comment: There seems to be many problems in my code. I want to improve ReLU function in tensorflow and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a custom layer, the custom layer object is first created, then the layer is made by calling the object.  The input parameter during initialization is the number of outputs, so let's say it's 10:

```
custom_layer = Mylayer(10)
```

Then you can use `custom_layer` to make the layer:

```
self.layer3 = custom_layer(tf.matmul(self.layer2, self.weights3) + self.bias3)
```

*Note:* As it's written, there will be an error because a `tf.matmul(self.layer2, self.weights3) + self.bias3` is a tensor with shape `(1,1)`.  The tensor will need to be evaluated before checking the condition `x < 0`, or perhaps use [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond).

**Edit:**
Here's a way to get the `newfx` with a conditional.  `tf.cond` needs to return the same tensor type whether it's true or false, so a `t_false` tensor is made for when the element is less than zero.

```
def call(self, x):
    t_false = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[0]]), dtype=tf.float32)
    newfx = tf.cond(x[0,0] < 0, lambda: t_false, lambda: x*1.5)
    return tf.matmul(newfx, self.kernel)
```

Comment: I fixed it as you said. Then a new error came out. It may be caused by what you pointed out at the note. I would like to use an improved version of the ReLU function. In that case, how should I change code?

Comment: {TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.}

Comment: I added info on using `tf.cond`.

Comment: Thanks.I added this code, but But a new error came out.`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() ` Where should I add a.any () or a.all ()?